# BigQuery - extract array from JSON String

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have a key with a value that is an array in a BQ table, see below

`"foo": [{"name":"bar","type":"FLOAT","value":"16.0"},{"name":"baz","type":"STRING","value":"F"}]`

and I am trying to extract the value of foo.

This is what I am trying:

`JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY('$.f.foo') AS fooBarBaz`

and then

`ARRAY_AGG(f.foo) AS fooBarBaz`

but this is not even returning null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below "to extract the value of foo"

```
select json_extract_array('{' || col || '}', '$.foo') foo_items
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]